# Checking overlapped subnets

Tags: python, overlap, subnet, cidr

I have 2 files that contain subnets in cidr format (212.234.96.0/24,
80.10.0.0/24, ...) liny by line.  I will like you to create a python script that will tell me overlapping subnets.  Input are file1 (list of subnets, more than 4000) and file2 (list that I want to check with file1). I want the output in file3 with the file2 subnets without overlapping.

For the other hand, I did this work in a shell script but the processing time is too long (for the +4000 subnets processing). Some people recommended that I should do this work in python. The problem is I'm new in python.

Thank you.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Rough outline:

1. read file1 into array `subnet` with subnet address, netmask, convert both to unsigned int32
2. read `entry` from file2, convert to unsigned int32
3. for each `subnet`element, `if (entry.uint32 & subnet.netmask.uint32) == (subnet.address.uint32 & subnet.netmask.uint32)` then `entry` is inside `subnet`
4. if `entry` is not in any subnet, write `entry` to file3

You can do this in pretty much any language you like.